# Should the seed query always return 1 row in hierarchial queries?

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn hierachial queries so I am seeing a syntax in the first where we need to initialize a seed value in the first query. My question is that should the intial seed query return only one value? or multiple values ?

Say if I need to perform recursion for multiple groups

Comment: Could you possibly be less vague? Give us an application subject for better understanding your question.

Comment: Not really relevant for this question, but you should always add a tag for the DBMS you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can return multiple values - all rows from the seed query serves as in input set for the next recursion.

For instance, with this schema

```
create table T1 (
  p int,
  c int
)

insert into T1 (p, c) values (0, 1)
insert into T1 (p, c) values (1, 2)
insert into T1 (p, c) values (2, 3)
insert into T1 (p, c) values (10, 11)
insert into T1 (p, c) values (11, 12)
insert into T1 (p, c) values (11, 13)
```

And this recursive query

```
WITH cte (p, c) as
(
  select p, c from T1 where p = 0 or p = 10
  union all
  select T1.p, T1.c from T1
  inner join cte on T1.p = cte.c
 )
 select * from cte
```

Notice that the base returns 2 rows and you get 2 branches (your multiple groups) from there.